# Change Table Row Background Color by Clicking Button in Different Table Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have two tables, one that has rows added to it dynamically, and one that holds that data to add.

[image]

The above image shows the tables. When the Edit button is clicked, the data from that row (in Table 1) is inserted into the fields below it ("Table 2") and the row that we are editing is highlighted in Table 1 using css.

```
var row = $(a).parent().parent();
row.children('td').css('background-color', '#FFFFCC');
```

Now assuming I can get the row index of the row that is being edited in table 1, how could I change that background back to white, if the user clicks the 'Cancel' button?

Comment: When you click edit, assuming you have a jquery on "click" event listener bound to the button, you can get the table row by:

var $parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');

If you have a jsfiddle, I can probably be more specific

Answer (score 0):

index being index of row to be arranged and tbl reference first table

```js
var index=1;
tbl = $("table")
$("#cancel").click(function(){
var rows = $('tr', tbl);
rows.eq(index).css("background-color", "white");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border=1 style="background-color:yellow">
  <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="cancel" value="cancel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just append an event to the 'onclick' event for the cancel link?

For Example:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(ev){
     var row = $(a).parent().parent();
     row.children('td').css('background-color', '#FFFFCC');
     //---Add the event to the cancel.
     $('.cancel').once('click', function(ev){
            row.children('td').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF'); //---The prev color     
     });

});
```

I have not tested this, but hope this can help or give you an alternative.